# Why do I always get a null ID when I acces it from firebase? (Jetpack Compose, Android Studio)

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, android-jetpack-compose

I want to get the ID of a firebase user and transfer it into a firestore cloud collection. My problem is: every time I sign up a user, it gets me a null id and I don't understand why.

This code is structured in MVVM

```
interface AuthRepository {

    val currentUser: FirebaseUser?

    val getUserId:String

    suspend fun signUpUser(email: String, password: String): Resource<FirebaseUser>

    suspend fun loginInUser(email: String, password: String): Resource<FirebaseUser>

    suspend fun createUser(email: String, password: String, code: String,id: String): Resource<FirebaseFirestore>

    suspend fun getData(): User

    fun logOut()
}


class AuthRepositoryIMPL @Inject constructor(
    private val firebase: Firebase,
    private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth,
    private val firebaseDB: FirebaseFirestore
): AuthRepository {

    override val currentUser: FirebaseUser?
        get() = firebaseAuth.currentUser

    override val getUserId: String
        get() = currentUser?.uid.toString().orEmpty()

    override suspend fun createUser(
        email: String,
        password: String,
        code: String,
        id: String,
    ): Resource<FirebaseFirestore> {
        return try {
            val user = mutableMapOf<String,Any>()
            user["user_id"]=id
            user["user_email"]=email
            user["user_password"]=password
            user["user_code"]=code

            val result = firebaseDB.collection("users").add(user).await()

            Resource.Succes(result.firestore)
        }catch (ex:Exception){
            ex.printStackTrace()
            Resource.Failure(ex)
        }
    }


@HiltViewModel
class AuthViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: AuthRepository
): ViewModel(){

    private val _signUpFlow = MutableStateFlow<Resource<FirebaseUser>?>(null)
    val signUpFlow: StateFlow<Resource<FirebaseUser>?> = _signUpFlow

    private val _loginFlow = MutableStateFlow<Resource<FirebaseUser>?>(null)
    val loginFlow: StateFlow<Resource<FirebaseUser>?> = _loginFlow

    private val _createUserFlow = MutableStateFlow<Resource<FirebaseFirestore>?>(null)
    val createUserFlow: MutableStateFlow<Resource<FirebaseFirestore>?> = _createUserFlow

    val stateUser = mutableStateOf(User())

    val currentUser: FirebaseUser?
        get() = repository.currentUser


    init {
        if (repository.currentUser != null) {
            _loginFlow.value = Resource.Succes(repository.currentUser!!)
        }

        getData()
    }

    fun signUpUser(email: String, password: String)
    =viewModelScope.launch{
        _signUpFlow.value=Resource.Loading
        val result = repository.signUpUser(email, password)
        _signUpFlow.value=result
    }

    fun loginInUser(email: String, password: String)
    =viewModelScope.launch(){
        _loginFlow.value=Resource.Loading
        val result = repository.loginInUser(email, password)
        _loginFlow.value=result
    }

    fun createUser(email: String,password: String,code: String,id: String)
    =viewModelScope.launch{
        _createUserFlow.value=Resource.Loading
        val result = repository.createUser(email,password, code,id)
        _createUserFlow.value=result
    }

    fun logOut(){
        repository.logOut()
        _signUpFlow.value=null
        _loginFlow.value=null
        _createUserFlow.value=null
    }

    private fun getData()
            =viewModelScope.launch{
        val result=repository.getData()
        stateUser.value=result
    }
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: Where exactly in your code are you getting null? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: Besides that, since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword). It's a working solution.

Comment: I checked it! Thank you!